# How to list all filenames under a directory using github api?

Tags: git, api, github

I need to list all the file names under a directory of my repository.

The following api can list filenames and directories from root directory.

`https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo-name/git/trees/master?recursive=1`

Found no appropriate api to list directory wise!

Comment: Note that the files in some path are specific to *that particular commit*. If I make a commit on `main` that has files `foo/one` and `foo/2`, and then in the next commit on main I have replaced `foo/one` with `foo/1` and `foo/2` with `foo/two`, it's impossible to say whether `foo` contains `one` and `2`, or `1` and `two`, without first picking some *commit*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}`

See documentation here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content